# Mysql: Count of orders based on reason,historical status and current status

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the count of orders and sum of revenue according to there history status and reason.

Following is my table structure.

**Order Table :-**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `id_order_item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unit_price` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_reason` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_item`),
  KEY `fk_reason` (`fk_reason`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**History Table :-**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_item_status_history` (
  `id_order_item_status_history` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_order_item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_order_item_status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT ''New status'',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_item_status_history`),
  KEY `fk_order_item` (`fk_order_item`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_item_status_history_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_order_item`) REFERENCES `order_item` (`id_order_item`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `order_item_status_history_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_order_item_status`) REFERENCES `order_item_status` (`id_order_item_status`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Status Table :-**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_item_status` (
  `id_order_item_status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deprecated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT ''0'',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_item_status`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Reason Table :-**

```
CREATE TABLE `reason` (
  `id_reason` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancel_reason`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

I need to group orders into following buckets,

1. Orders has status as 'Closed' and If Order was shipped before.(i.e.
   previous status of order is 'shipped')
2. Orders has status as 'Closed' and If Order was NOT shipped before(i.e. previous status of order is NOT 'shipped')
   *(in this case need to check current status as well as previous status of order. )*
3. Orders has status as 'fraud'
   *(in this case need to check current status only.)*
   ......

*How can I get the count or orders and there revenue according to bucket defined above.*
I am facing problem while counting orders in point 3 and 4 and get all counts in single query.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question. It would help if you would show what you've tried and some sample data and the desired result. Oh, and point 4.

Answer (score 1):

To get all those into one query you can use `CASE WHEN ..` like this

```
SELECT
whateverYouAreGroupingByIfNeeded,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' AND reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_whatever
SUM(CASE WHEN whatever = true THEN whateverYouWantToSummarize ELSE NULL END) AS sum_whatever
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY whatever
```

When you need specific help, it's best to show what you've tried.

P.S.: If you're having trouble with joining, read [this.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I dont have problem with joins I can able to get count of 1 and 2 point my problem is in 3 and 4 point and combine the result of this all counts together.